# Setting TextField limit

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, layout-manager

I created a swing application which has a string named `textField`, and I need to append in a string named `textArea`. My Problem is; when it appends, it doesn't align, since the names are different .

I want to make it accept 25 characters only, and if less than 25 were entered they are filled with spaces.

Is there any way this can be done?  I Have been on it since morning without making any headway.
Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Every Text Component in java associates with a model to maintain it's text content known as `Document`. A Document has: `DocumentListener` to listen to changes made to it which generates event on it's content update. you can also use `DocumentFilter` with `Document` to change how the text component's data is set. You can implement certain customizations either by installing a document filter or by replacing a text component's document with one of your own.

Check out the example and tutorial:

1. [How to write DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html)
2. [Implementing a Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter)
3. [DocumentSizeFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TextComponentDemoProject/src/components/DocumentSizeFilter.java)

Comment: Original poster -- go with this recommendation (1+), and don't use a KeyListener as others have recommended.